# How can I make this work with header files?

Tags: c++, header, g++

I have a very simple project. The file main.cpp creates a vector of floats, sorts them, then prints them.

I compile it with:

```
g++ main.cpp quickSort.cpp
```

If in main.cpp I change

```
#include "quickSort.h"
```

to

```
#include "quickSort.cpp"
```

it works fine.

How do I change this project so that it works with the header file?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include "quickSort.h"

#define MODULO 200
#define SIZE 1500

int main(){
    std::vector<float> data;
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        data.push_back(rand()%MODULO);

    data=quickSort(data);

    for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
        std::cout<<data[i]<<',';
    }
    std::cout<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

quickSort.cpp

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>

std::vector<T> quickSort(std::vector<T> data){

    if(data.size()==0)return data;
    int pivot=data[data.size()/2];

    std::vector<T> a;
    std::vector<T> b;
    std::vector<T> c;
    std::vector<T> ret;

    for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
        if(data[i]<pivot)a.push_back(data[i]);
        if(data[i]==pivot)b.push_back(data[i]);
        if(data[i]>pivot)c.push_back(data[i]);
    }

    a=quickSort(a);
    c=quickSort(c);

    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)ret.push_back(a[i]);
    for(int i=0;i<b.size();i++)ret.push_back(b[i]);
    for(int i=0;i<c.size();i++)ret.push_back(c[i]);

    return ret;
}
```

quickSort.h

```
#include <vector>
template<typename T>

std::vector<T> quickSort(std::vector<T> data);
```

Comment: Do you mean that quickSort.cpp is not being compiled and included in the project?  Depending on the platform there will be a way to add multiple files into the project.  For example, g++ main.cpp quickSort.cpp -I . -o qs will do it on Linux.  Visual Studio has a simple way to add multiple cpp files to the project.

Comment: @MatthewFisher I'm on Linux, what does the "-I . -o qs" do?

Comment: @KenY-N has a good point.  Your quickSort function is a template so it should be in the header file anyway.

Comment: The -I flag for g++ tells the complete to look in a particular directory.  The '.' means look in the current directory.   The -o flag names the output binary, in this case 'qs'

Comment: @MatthewFisher OK, so I should copy quickSort.cpp to quickSort.h?

Comment: yes and drop quickSort.cpp altogether

Comment: @MatthewFisher ok so why doesn't 'g++ main.cpp quickSort.cpp -I . -o qs' compile the project?

Comment: Have a look at the link @KenY-N posted.  template belong in header files since they are need at compile in other cpp files

Comment: @MatthewFisher I can't see the link you're referencing....

Comment: @MatthewFisher I think he deleted the link, but the message that my question is a duplicate probably refers to the same question. Even with that, I still don't know how to change my program so that it works with the header file...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180767/discussion-between-matthew-fisher-and-sam).